# Return a evaluation result directly or apply ternary operators before returning to enhance readability

Tags: java, coding-style

I am asking this question just to see how many people agree with me on this.
Situation is :
We had a piece of code where an API was returning a boolean value.
The return statement was written as

```
return (evaluator.isSuccess()?true:false);
```

Now my suggestion was to have code like

```
return evaluator.isSuccess()
```

Why statement you think is more readable ? first or second one ?

Comment: Why a down vote for this ? I am SO addict and could not find a better place to prove that second statement was more readable :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `return evaluator.isSuccess()`. its clearly readable tat success is an boolean.as it follows **java bean standard** for declaring a getter for boolean variables.

Answer (score 1):

certainly second one is readable and cleaner

First one is like

```
int i = someIntVal;
if(i == 10){
return 10;
}
return someIntVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Second one is short, better and reduces a condition check.

Should be preferred over the first one.